# Pytorch error: RuntimeError: input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 7, got 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am new to machine learning. Right now I am building a LSTM neural network. My input is 7 features and my output is 2 labels. However, when I put 7 into the input of the LSTM, I get this error. It works when I put 1 input, but I get very inaccurate results obviously.
I want to take in time input (hour, minute, second, etc as features) and predict lat & lon value (2 labels)
My code is below:

````
n_feature= feature_train.shape[1] # number of columns in input matrix
class LSTM(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_classes, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
        
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.seq_length = 7
        
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size,
                            num_layers=num_layers, batch_first=True)
        
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        h_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(
            self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size))
        c_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(
            self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size))
        # Propagate input through LSTM
        ula, (h_out, _) = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0))
        h_out = h_out.view(-1, self.hidden_size)    
        out = self.fc(h_out)   
        return out

num_epochs = 4
learning_rate = 0.01
input_size = 7
hidden_size =30
num_layers = 1

num_outputs = 2

lstm = LSTM(num_outputs, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()    # mean-squared error for regression
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(lstm.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# convert to tensor
xTrain = torch.tensor(np.array(feature_train).reshape(-1,n_feature), dtype = torch.float)
yTrain = torch.tensor(np.array(label_train).reshape(-1,2), dtype = torch.float)
xTrainValidation = torch.tensor(np.array(feature_validation).reshape(-1,n_feature), dtype = torch.float)
yTrainValidation = torch.tensor(np.array(label_validation).reshape(-1,2), dtype = torch.float)
xTrain = xTrain[:, :, None]
yTrain = yTrain[:, :, None]
xTrainValidation = xTrainValidation[:, :, None]
yTrainValidation = yTrainValidation[:, :, None]

# Train the model
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    outputs = lstm(xTrain)
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    outputs = outputs[:, :, None]

    # obtain the loss function
    loss = criterion(outputs, yTrain)
    
    loss.backward()
    
    optimizer.step()
    print("Epoch: %d, loss: %1.5f" % (epoch, loss.item()))
    torch.save(lstm, 'saved_model.pth')```
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbKcu.png
````

Answer (score 2):

Your LSTM input should have its last dimension equal to the `input_size`. Which is the value given on initialization of the [`nn.LSTM`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) module, you currently have it set to `7`. However, your model input is `xTrain` and has a shape of `(*, feature_train.shape[1], 1)`. This size mismatch is the reason behind this error.